# How to create a table with flexible column widths but fixed minimum that triggers a horizontal scroll if window is too small?

Tags: flutter-web

Using Flutter Web

I am able to achieve a fixed-width table (see below) that allows for horizontal scroll if the window is too narrow (i.e. on a phone). I also found a way to make a flexible width table that worked nicely using Flexible, but it broke when placed inside of a SingleChildScrollView. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Specific needs:

1. Table row with column 1 wider than the rest of the columns
2. All columns widen evenly if window is widened
3. Table row has minimum width
4. If the window is smaller than the minimum row width, user can scroll horizontally to see the overflow content

Thanks for any ideas!

```
                        SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Row( // Table header
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    Flexible(
                                      child: Container(
                                        constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: tableColumnLargeWidthMin, maxWidth: tableColumnLargeWidthMax, maxHeight: tableColumnLargeHeightMax, minHeight: tableColumnLargeHeightMin),
                                        child: Text(
                                            'Nerve',
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 15,
                                                color: colorTextLight,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                            )
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Flexible(
                                      child: Container(
                                        constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: tableColumnSmallWidthMin, maxWidth: tableColumnSmallWidthMax, maxHeight: tableColumnSmallHeightMax, minHeight: tableColumnSmallHeightMin),
                                        child: Text(
                                            'Amp (uV)',
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 15,
                                                color: colorTextLight,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                            )
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Flexible(
                                      child: Container(
                                        constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: tableColumnSmallWidthMin, maxWidth: tableColumnSmallWidthMax, maxHeight: tableColumnSmallHeightMax, minHeight: tableColumnSmallHeightMin),
                                        child: Text(
                                            'Lat (ms)',
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 15,
                                                color: colorTextLight,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                            )
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Flexible(
                                      child: Container(
                                        constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: tableColumnSmallWidthMin, maxWidth: tableColumnSmallWidthMax, maxHeight: tableColumnSmallHeightMax, minHeight: tableColumnSmallHeightMin),
                                        child: Text(
                                            'Dist (cm)',
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 15,
                                                color: colorTextLight,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                            )
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Flexible(
                                      child: Container(
                                        constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: tableColumnSmallWidthMin, maxWidth: tableColumnSmallWidthMax, maxHeight: tableColumnSmallHeightMax, minHeight: tableColumnSmallHeightMin),
                                        child: Text(
                                            'CV (m/s)',
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 15,
                                                color: colorTextLight,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                            )
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Divider(color: colorStructurePrimary),
                              for(var i in tableRowNCSSensory) i,
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```